# C++ class properties not updating properly

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a custom `galaxy` class which has a custom property `pos`.
`pos` is an instance of another custom class `Vector3D`.
A `Vector3D` has properties `x`, `y`, `z`. The arithmetic operations for Vector3D is basic vector math, the relevant ones below:

```
Vector3D Vector3D::operator+(const Vector3D& vec) {
    return Vector3D(x + vec.x, y + vec.y, z + vec.z);
}

Vector3D &Vector3D::operator+=(const Vector3D& vec) {
    x += vec.x;
    y += vec.y;
    z += vec.z;
    return *this;
}

Vector3D Vector3D::operator*(double val) {
    return Vector3D(x * val, y * val, z * val);
}
```

galaxy.cpp has some methods below:

```
void galaxy::updatePos(double dt) {
    pos += vel * dt;
}

void galaxy::updateVel(Vector3D accel, double dt) {
    vel += accel * dt;
}

void galaxy::updateStateVectors(Vector3D accel, double dt) {
    updateVel(accel, dt);
    updatePos(dt);
}
```

main.cpp calls method updateStateVectors as follows:

```
// within some while() loop

for (auto g : galaxies) {
    Vector3D accel = Vector3D();
    for (auto g2 : galaxies) {
        if (g != g2) {
            accel += g.getGravityAccelBy(g2);
        }
    }
    g.updateStateVectors(accel, dt);
}
```

(galaxies is a `std::vector<galaxy>`)

The problem is, the changes made to g.pos (or g.vel) within this for loop doesn't seem to persist. Each iteration on the while loop, I see that g.pos is back to its original value, disregarding the change it previously underwent in the for loop. What am I missing?

This might end up being a very silly mistake but I mainly code in Python and I've spent more time on this than I'd like to admit.

Comment: You should use reference. Change auto g to auto& g, the same for g2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

auto returns a copy of the object, so the original one is **copied**, not modified. You're then altering a **copy** of the original object.
Using & will make you reference the **original** one, so that you can alter it.

```
for (auto & g : galaxies) {
    Vector3D accel = Vector3D();
    for (auto & g2 : galaxies) {
        if (g != g2) {
            accel += g.getGravityAccelBy(g2);
        }
    }
    g.updateStateVectors(accel, dt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop `for (auto g : galaxies) {` is creating a copy of elements of `galaxies` to `g`. Therefore, changes to `g` are not saved to `galaxies`.

You should use a reference to the elements like `for (auto& g : galaxies) {` instead.

---

disclaimer:

I googled

- `site:stackoverflow.com [c++] range for not updated reference`
- `site:stackoverflow.com [c++] range-based-for not updated reference`
- `site:stackoverflow.com [c++] range-based-for not updated`
- `site:stackoverflow.com [c++] range-based change value`

but couldn't find a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this way to see if it works.

```
for (auto g& : galaxies) {
    Vector3D accel = Vector3D();
    for (auto g2 : galaxies) {
        if (g != g2) {
            accel += g.getGravityAccelBy(g2);
        }
    }
    g.updateStateVectors(accel, dt);
}
```

because there is a temporary object(ex: temp_g) generated in `for (auto g: galaxies)`, all changes are applied to the temporary object.